# missing parameter type on file upload with silhouette

Tags: scala, playframework

scala+playを学び始めて数ヶ月くらいです。
fileuploadを実装しようとしていて、silhouetteを使ってidentityを表示させるviewにもたせたいと考えているのですが、どう書くのが適切かがわかりません。
問題のメソッドは以下のものになります。

公式githubにあったfileuploadのサンプル
https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-fileupload-example/tree/2.5.x

silhouette 4.0.0
https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed/tree/4.0.0/app

```
  def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData(handleFilePartAsFile)) { implicit request =>

    val fileOption = request.body.file("picName").map {

      case FilePart(key, filename, contentType, file) =>
        logger.info(s"key = ${key}, filename = ${filename}, contentType = ${contentType}, file = $file")

        val data = operateOnTempFile(file)

        data

    }

    FileUploadFormSupport.picsave(_)

    silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>

    Future.successful(Ok(views.html.fileUpload2(request.identity,fileOption)))
    }
   }
```

> silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
>   Future.successful(Ok(views.html.fileUpload2(request.identity,fileOption)))
>   }

この部分をそのままuploadのメソッドに入れれば良いかと思い上のようにしたのですが、

> missing parameter type

のエラーが表示されてしまいます。

またrequestを request:Request と書き換えてみたものの、型パラメータがないとエラー表示されました。どう書くべきか、調べているところですが、見つけることはできていない状況です。

Comment: 本家での質問 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678326/missing-parameter-type-on-file-upload-with-silhouette

Comment: 英語版の方で解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 自己回答ができるのでご検討ください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。英語版のそのままですが記しておきました。

Answer (score 1):

英語版の方で解決しました。ありがとうございました。

以下のように記すべきだとご指摘いただきました。

```
def upload =
silhouette.SecuredAction.async(parse.multipartFormData(handleFilePartAsFile)) { 
  implicit request =>
    // Your upload code
}
```